# iMessage sksprite position not consistent with what is printed to console?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, imessage-extension

I have no idea how to get around this and have been at this for hours. I cannot adjust the position of my SKSpritenodes in accordance with `func didTransition(to presentationStyle:` in an iMessage extension.

I have tried to lay out my sprites according to this screen size because after printing, I confirmed this stays same regardless:

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
```

I have been doing this in the didTransition func to adjust positions & try to keep scene size consistent with the view:

```
 if(presentationStyle == .compact)
        {
            scene.uiToCompact()
        }
        else {
            scene.uiToFull()
        }
        skView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)
        scene.size = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)
```

I have tried creating a variable and continually setting the sprite's position to that variable in Update:

```
    ground.position = CGPoint(x: (scene?.size.width)!/2, y: groundHeight)
```

and in uiToCompact() or wherever modifying:

```
 groundHeight = screenSize.height * 0.4
```

And I have also tried just having this ALWAYS in update:

```
ground.position = CGPoint(x: (scene?.size.width)!/2, y: screenSize.height * 0.4)
```

Problem is nothing is working, EVEN THOUGH the console prints that the ground is always at same numerical position.

I am getting this: full to compact, in compact I am at the top of the scene looks like:

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is this impossible?

Comment: sorry. what exactly is the problem shown in picture?